# Estimate the complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Please help me about Estimate the complexity of the following algorithm:

Consider a search tree. Suppose that one node can expand into N child nodes. Estimate the complexity of the following algorithm

a. Breadth first search

b. Deep First Search

c. Iterative deepening search

Answer (score 0):

The book **Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach** discusses the complexities of the above-mentioned algorithms:
[image]

Comment: If you can show me step by step, please show me if you want, thank you so so much

Comment: @HuyTranquang it is well explained in the book